# Docpad does not run on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows-xp, npm, docpad

Node, npm (with -g), docpad and skeleton YUI PureCSS installed successfuly.

When I write `docpad run` in "my-website" folder, it says `command not found`.
When I write `docpad run` in an empty folder, it says the same.

I have investigated similar questions here, but answers did not help.

Environment: Windows XP, cygwin, heroku, aws

Comment: Strange... How did you install node? Does running `docpad.cmd run` work? Have you tried restarting your machine, as perhaps the `PATH` env variable isn't reflected yet?

Comment: I followed installation instructions here (http://docpad.org/docs/install). After restarting, I ran `docpad.cmd run` in "my-website" folder and still says `command not found`. Also I did the same in an empty folder. Should I write some PATH in environment variables? And if yes, what exactly should be there?

Comment: I have this on my PATH: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`, you should have something similar. If you do have, try to install another package globally (`npm install -g express` for example and then `express app ...`) to see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have the following PATH:`C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\cygwin\bin;`. After installing Express, what exactly should I do?

Comment: ok, I uninstalled everything and installed again, it works now. I have no idea what happened, though noticed that `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm` is empty before and also after install. Now, when docpad is running, can not open http://localhost:9778, also  http://localhost:9778/posts/hello.html; yuipurecss installed, index.html is full of lines. Any ideas?